# copy/pastes odd chars from a document written using hangul package

Tags: unicode, cjk

Recently i've been involved in writing document in Korean. I've managed to install the hangul package and write the following statement :

```
\usepackage{hangul} % pretty simple
```

everything was fine until I tried to print the document I wrote :
All the korean characters went like shuffled ascii chars (unreadable indeed).
If I try to copy/paste from the pdf to a notepad instance, the character are as if they were printed (therefore something really similar to that : *"öÎÇoe¿e@/¾úò¶|ÎÇoD¥2ÎÇoDÐ Wu|{èà"* - don't feel insulted).

I'm not used with fontenc and inputenc & co.
Where should i focus my figuring-out ?

I have the following settings :

- MiKTeX 2.9
- Using TeXstudio
- My document is UTF-8 (from TeXstudio editor options, not using any
  statements of input encoding in the document)

The structure of my document is as follow :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hangul}

\begin{document}
안녕, 한국어 이해할 수 있습니까?
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally been using **XeTeX** to perform the task.
That doesn't really answer my question, but as an alternative, I've been using **XeLaTeX** as the processing program.

I've installed from scratch **W32TeX** (*TeX for Windows*) following the installation steps from this link : http://w32tex.org/ .

And after a few little head-knocks, everything works just fine.
When I copy/paste characters from the *PDF* into a basic notepad, the Korean characters are well displayed (it was the main searched-result of my question).

- My document is UTF-8
- I compile my *.tex* file using **xelatex** command (no extra paramaters) :

  `xelatex <filename.tex>`

My simplified file looks like :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[space]{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Batang}
\title{한국어 파일}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: the result]

It compiles with just few warnings in the console (probably for debug verbose as some part of the bundle is continuously in development).

**Ps** : When I first tried to compile my *.tex* file, **xelatex** gave me a warning about **fontspec**, I don't quite remember what it said but no font were probably loaded so the processed *PDF* ain't show no Korean character. In order to cache the Korean font of your system you need to write **fc-cache -v** in the *cmd*. After that step **xelatex** outputs the *PDF* file with no trouble.

**Ps.2** : If you want to specify personal folder where your custom or downloaded fonts stand, you need to peek into **texmf/font/conf/local.conf** and add your folder(s) with the appropriate syntax : **`<dir>|absolute path|</dir>`** .
Don't forget to cache the font with the latter command!