# Seeing Korean characters in the editor

Tags: formatting

I use a tex template that includes Korean characters. When I compile it, the PDF document displays the Korean characters correctly. Yet, the Texshop text editor displays some rubbish characters instead. And when I actually type the Korean characters, after the compilation the PDF displays "?" instead of the characters. How do I get the formatting right?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

This is really impossible to answer without seeing a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), but I'm pretty sure you're dealing with the following problem:

The `.tex` file you're compiling loads [`CJK`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cjk) which assumes the [`EUC-KR`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Unix_Code#EUC-KR) encoding for Korean text. Your text editor, however, automatically loads the file with [`UTF-8`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding, as most modern text editors will do.

If the characters were entered into the `.tex` file with the `EUC-KR` encoding, you will see question marks � and various outlandish characters if you open the file with `UTF-8` encoding. The file will still compile just fine, since `CJK` correctly reads the `EUC-KR` encoded characters and produces a `.pdf` with Korean characters.

If you've opened the file with the `UTF-8` encoding and start typing Korean characters into the file, `CJK` can't interpret the input correctly, since it's expecting characters with the `EUC-KR` encoding. So `pdflatex` will probably throw an error, or it will produce a `.pdf` with garbage characters instead of Korean characters.

Your actual question "How do I get the formatting right?" is very vague, but if this means that you need to stick to your existing template, then make sure you switch the encoding of your file from `UTF-8` to `EUC-KR` before you enter any new Korean characters into the file, and also to be able to read the existing characters in your document.

This is all only guesswork, since it is impossible to know for sure what problem you're having or what's causing it when you're not providing a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Please always do so in the future.

Here's an example. The following document was typed with `EUC-KR` encoding, but below I've opened it with the standard `UTF-8` encoding, and it looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJK}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}[HL]{KS}{mj}
�ȳ��ϼ���
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

If I compile this, it nevertheless correctly produces this output:
[image]

If I instead load the file with `EUC-KR` encoding, I see this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJK}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}[HL]{KS}{mj}
안녕하세요
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

### pdflatex

Using this engine, you can still adopt [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17144/4778) posted by Medina (remember to set `babel` to English so the Table of Contents, etc, will be in English).

According to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68992/4778), however, you need the [**`uhc`**](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/uhc) font package installed in order to be able to use `mj`.

### xelatex

If you're already using xelatex (or if you can switch for one document), it's easier since you don't need to enclose Korean in its own environment. However you need to choose a font, otherwise the document typesets without errors but you won't see any glyphs (except for the latin ones). Try commenting out the command `\setmainfont{}` then compiling, and you'll see what I mean.

The package `fontspec` must be loaded in order for the command above to work. This allows you to set a font. If you load `xeCJK`, you can also use the command `\setCJKmainfont{}` to set a font for your language. Here's an example with `Nanum Myeongjo Regular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xeCJK}

\setmainfont{Century Gothic}
\setCJKmainfont{NanumMyeongjo}

\begin{document}

\centering\Huge\noindent
This is some text in Latin script. And now some Korean:
이 FAQ 은 자주 반복되는 질문과 그에 대한 대답을 간단명료한 양식으로 모아 엮어졌습니다.

\end{document}
```