# I'm not able to make use of cjk package for korean language

Tags: errors, packages, installing, cjk

I have written a table of all the consonant/vowel combinations in korean and noticed that I needed a package in order to show them. So now I'm trying to use the `cjk` package and I've seen that I should use this command in order to show the korean characters:

```
\begin{CJK}{KS}{fs}
\end{CJK}
```

The thing is that it gives me an error.

```
Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed for the following reason: The kmj source file could not be found. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
C:/Users/Alessandro/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-makemf.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.4) Couldn't find 'kmj.cfg'

Sorry, but miktex-maketfm did not succeed for the following reason: No creation rule for font kmj07. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
C:/Users/Alessandro/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-maketfm.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed for the following reason: The kmj source file could not be found. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
C:/Users/Alessandro/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-makemf.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.4) Couldn't find 'kmj.cfg'

Sorry, but miktex-maketfm did not succeed for the following reason: No creation rule for font kmj07. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
C:/Users/Alessandro/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-maketfm.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed for the following reason: The kmj source file could not be found. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
C:/Users/Alessandro/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-makemf.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.4) Couldn't find 'kmj.cfg'

Sorry, but miktex-maketfm did not succeed for the following reason: No creation rule for font kmj08. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
C:/Users/Alessandro/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-maketfm.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed for the following reason: The kmj source file could not be found. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
C:/Users/Alessandro/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-makemf.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.4) Couldn't find 'kmj.cfg'

Sorry, but miktex-maketfm did not succeed for the following reason: No creation rule for font kmj09.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
C:/Users/Alessandro/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-maketfm.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed for the following reason: The kmj source file could not be found. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
C:/Users/Alessandro/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-makemf.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.4) Couldn't find 'kmj.cfg'

Sorry, but miktex-maketfm did not succeed for the following reason: No creation rule for font kmj10.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
C:/Users/Alessandro/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-maketfm.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed for the following reason: The ksso source file could not be found. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
C:/Users/Alessandro/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-makemf.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.4) Couldn't find 'hanja65.hbf'

Sorry, but miktex-maketfm did not succeed for the following reason: No creation rule for font ksso1727. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
C:/Users/Alessandro/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-maketfm.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed for the following reason: The ksso source file could not be found. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
C:/Users/Alessandro/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-makemf.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.4) Couldn't find 'hanja65.hbf'

Sorry, but miktex-maketfm did not succeed for the following reason: No creation rule for font ksso1727. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
C:/Users/Alessandro/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-maketfm.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed for the following reason: The ksso source file could not be found. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
C:/Users/Alessandro/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-makemf.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
```

And this error goes on loop until I stop it and says this:

```
Error: Command crashed: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "List of Formulas".tex

Process exited with error(s)
```

The first log gives me this:
`2017-04-02 21:16:07,738+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - The kmj source file could not be found.
2017-04-02 21:16:10,502+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - The kmj source file could not be found.
2017-04-02 21:16:13,348+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - The kmj source file could not be found.
2017-04-02 21:16:16,127+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - The kmj source file could not be found.
2017-04-02 21:16:18,974+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - The kmj source file could not be found.
2017-04-02 21:16:21,715+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - The ksso source file could not be found.
2017-04-02 21:16:25,405+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - The ksso source file could not be found.
2017-04-02 21:16:30,550+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - The ksso source file could not be found.`
The second one this:
`2017-04-02 21:16:07,238+0200 INFO  makex - Running miktex-makemf.exe...
2017-04-02 21:16:07,855+0200 INFO  makex - Running hbf2gf.exe...
2017-04-02 21:16:09,174+0200 FATAL miktex-maketfm - No creation rule for font kmj07.
2017-04-02 21:16:09,999+0200 INFO  makex - Running miktex-makemf.exe...
2017-04-02 21:16:10,616+0200 INFO  makex - Running hbf2gf.exe...
2017-04-02 21:16:11,920+0200 FATAL miktex-maketfm - No creation rule for font kmj07.
2017-04-02 21:16:12,757+0200 INFO  makex - Running miktex-makemf.exe...
2017-04-02 21:16:13,462+0200 INFO  makex - Running hbf2gf.exe...
2017-04-02 21:16:14,780+0200 FATAL miktex-maketfm - No creation rule for font kmj08.
2017-04-02 21:16:15,618+0200 INFO  makex - Running miktex-makemf.exe...
2017-04-02 21:16:16,242+0200 INFO  makex - Running hbf2gf.exe...
2017-04-02 21:16:17,531+0200 FATAL miktex-maketfm - No creation rule for font kmj09.
2017-04-02 21:16:18,363+0200 INFO  makex - Running miktex-makemf.exe...
2017-04-02 21:16:19,087+0200 INFO  makex - Running hbf2gf.exe...
2017-04-02 21:16:20,379+0200 FATAL miktex-maketfm - No creation rule for font kmj10.
2017-04-02 21:16:21,215+0200 INFO  makex - Running miktex-makemf.exe...
2017-04-02 21:16:21,830+0200 INFO  makex - Running hbf2gf.exe...
2017-04-02 21:16:23,159+0200 FATAL miktex-maketfm - No creation rule for font ksso1727.
2017-04-02 21:16:24,536+0200 INFO  makex - Running miktex-makemf.exe...
2017-04-02 21:16:25,594+0200 INFO  makex - Running hbf2gf.exe...
2017-04-02 21:16:28,068+0200 FATAL miktex-maketfm - No creation rule for font ksso1727.
2017-04-02 21:16:29,604+0200 INFO  makex - Running miktex-makemf.exe...
2017-04-02 21:16:30,735+0200 INFO  makex - Running hbf2gf.exe...
2017-04-02 21:16:33,334+0200 FATAL miktex-maketfm - No creation rule for font ksso1728.`

I really don't understand what's the problem here. Everything is installed like in this other post: [MiKTeX 2.9 CJK Korean font not found error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68707/miktex-2-9-cjk-korean-font-not-found-error)
I've tried like in the answer given with `UTF8` and `mj` but it gives me the same errors but, this time, with `uwmj.cfg` and all the source files not being able to be found.
I even tried on a new file and same errors. Did I skip something?

**EDIT**: Here's a little MWE that has been asked to me:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{cjk}

\begin{document}
    \begin{CJK}{KS}{mj}
        가 까 카 나 다 따
    \end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT 2**: I think I'm getting kind of close to what I want. I reduced the error messages to just two with this one:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\begin{document}
    \begin{CJK}{UTF8}{mj}
        가 까 카 나 다 따
    \end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

Error messages:

```
Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed for the following reason: The uwmjac source file could not be found. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
C:/Users/Alessandro/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-makemf.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.4) Couldn't find `uwmj.cfg'

Sorry, but miktex-maketfm did not succeed for the following reason: No creation rule for font uwmjac. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
C:/Users/Alessandro/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-maketfm.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

Process exited with error(s)
```

Log files errors:
`2017-04-04 19:22:42,128+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - The uwmjac source file could not be found.`
`2017-04-04 19:22:41,544+0200 INFO  makex - Running miktex-makemf.exe...
2017-04-04 19:22:42,291+0200 INFO  makex - Running hbf2gf.exe...
2017-04-04 19:22:43,475+0200 FATAL miktex-maketfm - No creation rule for font uwmjac.`

**EDIT 3**: If I write in Japanese or Chinese it all works fine and I can see the characters on the preview. The problems seems to lie specifically on the korean font but I installed all the existing packages related to cjk through the package manager.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx  Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE):  https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with '\documentclass‘ and ending with '\end{document}'

Comment: @Bobyandbob I added the MWE.

Comment: Is XeLaTeX an option? If so, your life will be lots & lots easier.

Comment: @cfr XeLaTeX? Sorry, I'm kind of new to LaTeX. I only have MikTeX and TeXstudio.

Comment: It is an alternative to pdfLaTeX which would let you use opentype fonts, for example, installed on your system. It supports unicode out-of-the-box and makes typesetting non-Latin scripts much easier. pdfLaTeX can only use fonts with no more than 256 slots. I don't know much about CJK scripts but, as I understand it, this is itself quite problematic. XeLaTeX isn't limited in this way. And it doesn't depend on special support files for fonts or require them to be specially installed for use with TeX. MikTeX supplies XeLaTeX, so you certainly have access to it.

Comment: @cfr I am actually writing a document class "book" and I have the korean written on another file while other files are about other stuff. Is it possible to use XeLaTeX on only that file and the others with only pdfLaTeX and still be able to compile all together? Or does this create problems?

Comment: You can't do that, no. Either you compile with XeTeX or with pdfTeX or with whatever. You could compile an image or part of a document and then include it in its already compiled state, but that is not usually very satisfactory except in the case of images.

Comment: @cfr In what way is not satisfactory? It won't be well formatted? Anyway, it seems I'm then forced to find a way to use this package then, although I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Your second edit works for me with no errors. Do you see the same errors if you add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` before `\begin{document}`? You may also want to take a look at this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68992/24974

Comment: @Alex It makes it hard to keep everything consistent.

Comment: @erik Yes, same error. And I've checked that answer too but it doesn't say anything about how to install the missing korean font. "In MiKTeX (as you use), cjk-fonts package myoungjo Type1 fonts but there seems no .tfm files and LaTeX font definition (.fd) files to support these files. I can't make any working example without modifying the files, sorry." He modifies the file. What files? How?

Comment: @erik He then says this: "If you use KS input encoding, there are more fonts available, but you may have to install the hlatex-fonts package manually. It is an advanced topic for most users, I won't explain too much here." How to install that package manually?

Comment: @erik I'm curious. Could you tell me all the packages that you have for writing in korean?

Comment: @Alex I only have the standard TeXLive packages installed, and I never write in Korean, but it looks like the `uhc` package has the fonts you need. I suggest you make sure you have an up-to-date version installed on your system. The only other suggestion I have is make sure your encoding is utf-8.

Comment: @erik Would a standard TeXLive package work on TeXstudio? I may as well try that too at this point... And yes, I have UTF-8 as encoding.

Comment: @Alex Yes, because TeXstudio is just the editor/front-end, and there is little significant difference between MiKTeX and TeXLive. MiKTeX should ask you to install any missing packages on-the-fly, so I assume you have everything you need. If your encoding is also correct, then the only other suggestion I have is to update your installation and start googling font issues. (I'm not on Windows, so I can't help there.) Good luck!

Comment: @erik Oh, so TeXLive is like MiKTeX! I thought TeXLive was another editor like TeXstudio. Anyway, sometimes MiKTeX is unable to find the packages I want when doing it on-the-fly so I end up doing it through the package manager. And I've already googled for font issues but they all say the same things, which is to install these packages and stuff. I think I'll be forced to use XeLaTeX separately on this file and then unite the final product with the one compiled with pdfLaTeX.